# Pest on fenugreek

Tags: species-identification, botany, agriculture, pest-control

I need help identifying this pest on a fenugreek leaf. It is very common Maharashtra and Karnataka (India), and probably other states as well. Some of the leaves in the fenugreek bunches bought in the market have this kind of a distinct pattern. I am not able to pinpoint the exact orientation and shape/size of this organism on the leaf so I'll be glad to accept any help for that as well.
[image]

Comment: It is some kind of leaf miner, which should narrow the search. I am not sure what species.